# Question about "heap pollution" at solution#1 in "Effective Java Item#29 Favor Generic Types"

Tags: java, generics, effective-java

I am reading Effective Java Item#29 Favor Generic Types.

I'm confused about heap pollution that this item mentioned when it talked about the reason to choose solution#1 or solution#2.

> Both techniques for eliminating the generic array creation have their
> adherents. The first is more readable: the array is declared to be of
> type E[], clearly indicating that it contains only E instances. It is
> also more concise: in a typical generic class, you read from the array
> at many points in the code; the first technique requires only a single
> cast (where the array is created), while the second requires a
> separate cast each time an array element is read. Thus, the first
> technique is preferable and more commonly used in practice. It does,
> however, cause heap pollution (Item 32): the runtime type of the array
> does not match its compile-time type (unless E happens to be Object).
> This makes some programmers sufficiently queasy that they opt for the
> second technique, though the heap pollution is harmless in this
> situation.

In my understanding, that means some programmers might concern about "heap pullution" at solution#1, so they might choose solution#2.
Is my understanind correcyt?
Could Java expert help me to figure out why heap pollution might happen at solution#1 or solution#2?

**Original Code without Generic**

```
// Object-based collection - a prime candidate for generics
public class Stack {
    private Object[] elements;
    private int size = 0;
    private static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;

    public Stack() {
        elements = new Object[DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY];
    }

    public void push(Object e) {
        ensureCapacity();
        elements[size++] = e;
    }

    public Object pop() {
        if (size == 0)
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        Object result = elements[--size];
        elements[size] = null; // Eliminate obsolete reference
        return result;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    private void ensureCapacity() {
        if (elements.length == size)
            elements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, 2 * size + 1);
    }
}
```

**solution#1 for Generic**

```
public class Stack<E> {
    private E[] elements;
    private int size = 0;
    private static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;

    public Stack() {
        elements = (E[]) new Object[DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY];
    }

    public void push(E e) {
        ensureCapacity();
        elements[size++] = e;
    }

    public E pop() {
        if (size == 0)
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        E result = elements[--size];
        elements[size] = null; // Eliminate obsolete reference
        return result;
    }
    ... // no changes in isEmpty or ensureCapacity
}
```

**solution#2 for Generic**

```
public class Stack<E> {
    private Object[] elements;
    private int size = 0;
    private static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;

    public Stack() {
        elements = new Object[DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY]; 
    }

    public void push(E e) {
        ensureCapacity();
        elements[size++] = e;
    }

    public E pop() {
        if (size == 0)
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        E result = (E) elements[--size];
        elements[size] = null; // Eliminate obsolete reference
        return result;
    }
    ... // no changes in isEmpty or ensureCapacity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In solution #2 you have to cast in pop method what is not recommended. Your code is not type-safety. If methods are more complicated it can generate bugs. You don't have any benefits because of it.

Another similar example is method get. You have to cast also:

```
public E get(int n) {
    return (E) elements[n];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help! Do you mean "heap pollution" might happen at Solution#2 instead of Solution#1? (even though the author said it is harmless in this situation) But why solution#1 doesn't have "heap pollution" either? Thanks!